# PHP5 and MySQL tutorials?

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to convert my page to php5, but I can't seem to find any good tutorials conserning databases. (appart from sites that us the same methods as  in PHP4)
I know from friends however that the whole thing changed quite a bit, so could anyone help me here?

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Why did this get closed? I'm sorry if I did something wrong, but I really don't see it. I have been on php.net but I always have trouble understanding things the way they put it and was hoping for some more "layman" tutorials.

Comment: You're asking for a code-review without a specific problem. The help you're requesting "*will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion*"

Comment: The problem was converting it to PHP5, but I see how that is not really a problem (though very handy for me as I learn mostly from examples). If I remove that, can this thread be opened again?

Comment: SO is not crowd-source code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and don't `SELECT *` unless you need to.